# How can i have one image with multiple products?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, multiple

I'm developing a website for jewelry, so basically in one image a model is showing 3 products (`earnings, a ring and a neckless)`. When a client clicks on the image, it basically has to show the list of 3 products and its prices. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your looking for is a group product. A group product is essentially a product page in which you can show multiple child products and have them be added to the cart depending on the quantity entered for each one.

If you need a hand setting one up I would recommend taking a look at the ***[new user guide](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-grouped.html?Highlight=Grouped)***